# Java ArrayList with object in a loop

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I know the name of the object in the `ArrayList` when it is declared in a loop?
I can get it by an index but I don't know the name of it to locate/know if it is in the `ArrayList`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<UserClasss> userList = new ArrayList<UserClasss>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            UserClasss user = new UserClasss();
            user.setName("name"+i);
            user.setAge((int)(Math.random()*80));
            userList.add(user);
        }
        for (UserClasss forUser:userList){
            System.out.println(forUser.getName());
            System.out.println(forUser.getAge());
        }


        //how can i know if contains it here?
        //userList.contains(user);
        //and how do i know the index of it?
        //userList.indexOf(user);


    }
}

class UserClasss {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public void setName(String s){
        name = s;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setAge(int i){
        age = i;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To find your user class inside the List you must override the equals and hash code methods in the class `UserClasss`.

By doing that the contains() and indexOf() methods will be able to find them inside the `Collection`.

P.S. eclipse and some other IDE's can generate these methods for you.

code to add (generate by eclipse):

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + age;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        UserClasss other = (UserClasss) obj;
        if (age != other.age)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use contains() and indexOf(), but your UserClass should have an equals() method

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

that returns true if obj is equals to itself. In your case, you should compare the name.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if (! (obj instanceof UserClass) {
      return false;
   }
   return this.name.equals((UserClass)obj).name );
}
```

Of course, you can compare all the attributes you wanted.

Comment: it's always good to override both `hashCode()` and `equals()` and not just one